# Update with sub-query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want let my SQL query calculate with the sum and update the new data into my columns, but when I try my query this error is shown:

> ERROR #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Pflanzen2017' for update in FROM clause

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE Pflanzen2017 SET Ernteanteil = (SELECT Anzahl / (SELECT SUM(Anzahl) FROM Pflanzen2017))
```

Could anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Too many errors in that query... Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: The error message is not related to this query. You have Pflanzen table and target table of the error message is student. Check out your post and edit it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit as follows:

```
update pflanzen2017, 
(select sum(anzahl) as sumanzahl from pflanzen2017) as toupdate
set pflanzen2017.ernteanteil = pflanzen2017.anzahl/toupdate.sumanzahl;
```

You can see an example of a working version of this [here](http://rextester.com/ELZI94842).
I created a very simple `Pflanzen` table with only the two columns you need here for the update.

Comment: the same as above

Comment: well, i had added also a working copy :) did you check it out?

Comment: thank you very much! I edited your sql a little bit, but no it's working!

Comment: The working sql is: update Pflanzen2017 JOIN(select sum(Anzahl) as sumanzahl from Pflanzen2017) as toupdate
set Pflanzen2017.Ernteanteil = Pflanzen2017.Anzahl/toupdate.sumanzahl